# Simple html market?

Tags: html

Hey guys this is my question

If you go to 372designs.com and see one of the portfolio pages will be the lay out

Under the.description text there will be a buy button

How do I code that buy button to make it.so that it takes them to a paypal or someother page and have them pay and be redirect back to 372designs and the file they click the buy button under is the file that's downloaded. Is this html or someother type of coding?

I tried to be as descriptive as I could and hopefully its clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the PayPal Digital Goods API. The folloing link will give you all the things you need + implementation examples:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/use-cases/digital-goods

Comment: Thank you for the link ill check it when my computers don't charging :)